# .htaccess and 302 vs 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site on a managed server which for historical reasons carries versions in subfolders which are used for development, testing and production respectively.  The different versions are managed through forks of a git repo.

I need to:

ensure that all requests are https 
all requests to the main URL are referred to the production site
all requests to pages which exist are honoured

I have an .htaccess file in the root which works perfectly but for one problem.  If someone visits the site requesting

```
domain.co.uk www.domain.co.uk   or http://www.domain.co.uk
```

They are redirected correctly to

```
https://www.domain.com/production/index.php
```

but with a 302 header

If someone visits the site requesting

```
https://www.domain.com/
```

They are again redirected correctly, but this time with a 301 permanent redirect header.

For SEO purposes I want to be able to get a 301 header for every redirect.

Here is my .htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
# check for no www on url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
# check protocol
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
# send everything to production
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /production/ [R=301,L,NE]
```

If I had access to the server, I suspect I might find this easier, but this site is hosted on a shared server running lightspeed.

At a real loss on this one - I'm a pretty good programmer, but .htaccess is not my forte!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are 2 errors in your htaccess : 1) The order of rules is incorrect, 2) Your #check protocall rule is missing rewrite flags **[R=301]** ,So it is  using default 302 to redirect.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!!